switch no entra en algunos case en JAVA
Realice un ejercicio usando un vector en el que registro 15 numeros enteros, tengo un menu de 5 opciones controlado por un ciclo do while y dentro un switch con 4 cases:
La opcion 1: es el llenado del vector
La opcion 2:  es la impresion del vector
La opcion 3: es imprinir el promedio de los numeros que ocupan las pocisiones impares dentro del vector
La opcion 4: es imprimir la suma de los numeros que ocupan pocisiones pares dentro del vector
Y la opcion 5: es para finalizar el ciclo do while
El problema es que puedo llenar e imprimir los numeros de mi vector, pero cuando quiero acceder al case 3 y al case 4 mi programa no lee la opcion.
Se los agradeceria mucho.
Este es el codigo:
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Programa que contiene un vector de 15 datos");
    //variables iteradoras
    int x = 0, i = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    //Variable menu switch
    int op=0;
    //Variables almacenadoras
    int suma = 0, suma2 = 0;
    //Variables auxiliares
    int prom;
    //vector
    int n [] = new int [15];
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Lista de opciones:");
        System.out.println("1: Registrar datos en el vector");
        System.out.println("2: Leer los datos de vector");
        System.out.println("3: Promedio de las pocisiones impares");
        System.out.println("4: Suma de las pocisiones pares");
        System.out.println("5: Salir");
        System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada");
        op=leer.nextInt();
        switch(op){
        
            case 1:
                for (x=0;x<15;x++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de el dato "+(x+1));
                    n[x]=leer.nextInt();
                }
            break;
            
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Los datos de su vector son: ");
                for (i=0;i<15;i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(n[i]+" | "); 
                }
            break;
            
            case 3:
                for (y=1;y<15;y=+2)
                {
                    suma=suma+n[y];
                }
                prom=suma/7;
                System.out.println("El promedio de las pocisiones impares es:"+prom);
                break;
            
            case 4:
                for (z=0;z<15;z=+2)
                {
                    suma2=suma2+n[z];
                }  
                System.out.println("La suma de las pocisiones pares es: "+suma2);
                break;
        }
    }while(op!=5);
}

}

El problema en tu código radica en cómo estás incrementando tus iteradores en los casos 3 y 4 del switch. Estás usando y=+2 y z=+2, lo cual no está incrementando correctamente las variables. Deberías usar y+=2 y z+=2 para incrementar en 2 unidades en cada iteración.
`Código corregido:``
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Programa que contiene un vector de 15 datos");
        //variables iteradoras
        int x = 0, i = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
        //Variable menu switch
        int op = 0;
        //Variables almacenadoras
        int suma = 0, suma2 = 0;
        //Variables auxiliares
        int prom;
        //vector
        int n[] = new int[15];
        do {
            System.out.println("Lista de opciones:");
            System.out.println("1: Registrar datos en el vector");
            System.out.println("2: Leer los datos de vector");
            System.out.println("3: Promedio de las pocisiones impares");
            System.out.println("4: Suma de las pocisiones pares");
            System.out.println("5: Salir");
            System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada");
            op = leer.nextInt();
            switch (op) {

                case 1:
                    for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de el dato " + (x + 1));
                        n[x] = leer.nextInt();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Los datos de su vector son: ");
                    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                        System.out.print(n[i] + " | ");
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    for (y = 1; y < 15; y += 2) {
                        suma += n[y];
                    }
                    prom = suma / 7;
                    System.out.println("__________________________________________");
                    System.out.println("El promedio de las pocisiones impares es:" + prom);
                    System.out.println("__________________________________________");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    for (z = 0; z < 15; z += 2) {
                        suma2 += n[z];
                    }
                    System.out.println("__________________________________________");
                    System.out.println("La suma de las pocisiones pares es: " + suma2);
                    System.out.println("__________________________________________");
                    break;
            }
        } while (op != 5);
    }
}




Woow muchísimas gracias, la verdad que fue un error muy tonto de mi parte, nunca se me olvidará como hacer correctamente el incremento jajaja.
